# Sending message body to email with PrivateMsg module

Tags: privatemsg

PrivateMsg Module sends email notifications that you have received a message to users. How to send the "Message Body" to the user in the email. So no need to login and see the message .

Any clues ?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you navigate to `admin/config/messaging/privatemsg`, you will find the template of mail which  get send by system when somebody private message to message some user.

You can modify the template. If you navigate to tokens below, you will find several tokens, one is - **[privatemsg_message:original:body]**. You can insert it in above template to send it in mail according to your need.

I think you need [Token](https://drupal.org/project/token) module for all this & I hope you must have this installed in your instance.